# Checking div properties once page has loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

A couple times now I have wanted to check element sizes as the page loads. I've been doing that using `$(document).ready();`, but find that often the properties are null. The same is true if I use `$(window).load();`.

To get around this I have been using a bit of a hack, where I recursively recall the function if the element is not set.

Question: Is there a better approach in terms of professionalism?

```
var makeMusic = {

    init: function() {
        if ($('#bloc-1').height() == null) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                makeMusic.init() ########## THIS IS THE HACK ##########
            }, 10)
        } else {
            makeMusic.height = $('#bloc-1').height();
            makeMusic.width = $('#bloc-1').width();
        }       
        makeMusic.watchExperience();
    },

    watchExperience: function() {
      //Some stuff
    }
}


var Main = {
    run: function() {
        makeMusic.init();
    }
}

$(document).ready(Main.run());
```

Comment: Unusual; Only thing that comes to mind, but probably not that: are those elements also created on doc.ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a hack at all. The issue here is that `Main.run` function is invoked before `document.ready()` is fired. You should:

```
$(document).ready(Main.run);
```

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(Main.run());
```

When you add `()` to the function name interpeter invokes it as soon as the line is reached.

When passing a callback, you should only pass a reference to the function.

Comment: I see, so Main.run() was being invoked in this case before .ready()?

Comment: Yep, as soon as the interpeter reached the document.ready line, the main.run was invoked, evaluated and it's return value passed into the document.ready function

Comment: So instead of passing it a function object to call back, you passed null, since Main.run has no return value

Answer (score 1):

In terms of proffessionalism i think its better to put your code in a namespace like this:

```
 var app = window.app || {};
 app.set = {};
 app.set.makeMusic = (function(){

     // private members
     this.height = "";
     this.width = "";

     var init = function() {
         height = $('#bloc-1').height();
         width = $('#bloc-1').width();
         alert(height + " " + width);
     };

     //public interface
     return {
         init: init
     };

 })(); // self invoked

 $(function(){
     app.set.makeMusic.init();
 });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6trtrqv/)

Comment: what exactly is the return init function doing here? And how is the selector working with a function? I would have thought that was for html elements...